# Ag-Grid Link with link in the cell in the group

Tags: ag-grid

i am trying to achive clickable link inside the group

just like this

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/anJSAE?p=preview

but for data inside the group

but because there is two cellrender (for group and for hyperlink) will happen. ag-grid is not accepting it.

can you please let me understand, is that achivable

my plunker

https://embed.plnkr.co/gMfQXY/

Comment: Can't imagine a reason why you need to have both handlers on one cell, but just in case - you need to create own `groupCellRenderer` and handle 'collapse' and 'link click' inside with own logic.

Comment: i dont want to use both handler but i wanted to make the group cell clickable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ag-grid : Clickable link in group cell rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52252551/ag-grid-clickable-link-in-group-cell-rendered)