# ag-grid : Clickable link in group cell rendered

Tags: ag-grid

I am trying to make clicable link in group (group and its child should be clickable, should be like a link)

i'm not able to make it because for a clickable link i need to create a cellrenderer but in this case group cellredered in already there

```
here is my plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/gMfQXY?p=preview
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to have it in one column? You can define 'dummy' column exactly for group handling and then, the first column with own `cellRenderer` for the link.

Anyway, you can use `innerCellRenderer` inside `cellRendererParams`- I suppose it's exactly as you looking for.

> innerRenderer: The renderer to use for inside the cell (after grouping functions are added).

```
cellRenderer:'agGroupCellRenderer',
// provide extra params to the cellRenderer
cellRendererParams: {
    suppressCount: true, // turn off the row count
    suppressDoubleClickExpand: true, // turn off double click for expand
    checkbox: true, // enable checkbox selection
    innerRenderer: myInnerRenderer, // provide an inner renderer
    footerValueGetter: myFooterValueGetter // provide a footer value getter
}
```

Code part from [official doc](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/#grid-renderer-aggroupcellrenderer)